# ${p^km \choose p^k} \equiv m \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime number and $m, k$ two positive integers. Then ${p^km \choose p^k} \equiv m \pmod p$.
I've been trying to demonstrate this lemme all the day. Have you got any suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: See http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math101aF07/Math101a_notesA6.pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a special case of [Lucas's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem).

Comment: Ah good to know; I was about to type out my own answer which is easily superseded by Lucas's theorem!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a group action proof.  Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $p^km$ and let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ of order $p^k$.  Let $H$ act on the set $X$ of subsets of $G$ of size $p^k$.  Then since $H$ is a $p$-group, the number of fixed points of $H$ on $X$ is congruent to the size of $X$ modulo $p$.  But a subset of size $p^k$ is fixed by $H$ iff it is a coset of $H$.  Since there are $m$ cosets of $H$, we conclude that $\binom{p^km}{p^k}=|X|\equiv m\bmod p$.

Comment: How do you prove that if $A \subseteq G$ has size $p^{k}$ and it is fixed by $H$, then $A$ must be a coset? I only managed to prove the other direction, namely, every coset has $p^{k}$ elements and is fixed by $H$.

Comment: @DiegoMathemagician, the orbits of $H$ acting on $G$ are the cosets and so if $H$ fixes $A$, that is $A$ is invariant under $H$, then $A$ must be a union of cosets.  Since $|A|=|H|$, it can only be that $A$ is a single coset.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you! Sorry for the late reply.