# $\binom{mp^n}{p^n}\cong m$ (mod $p$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I proved that $\binom{mp^n}{p^n}\cong m$ (mod $p$) for every prime number $p$ and positive integer $m$. But in my book $m$ is assumed to be coprime to $p$, while my proof did not make use of that assumption. Is the identity without that assumption really correct?

Proof sketch:
We first expand $(1+x)^{mp^n}$ in the field $\mathbb F_p$ using the binomial theorem. Then we expand it in another way: since $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$ in $\mathbb F_p$, we have $(1+x)^{mp^n}=(1+x^{p^n})^m$. Now equating the coefficients of $x^{p^n}$, we get the result.

Comment: What is your proof? If we had that, we could tell you either that you're correct, or pinpoint for you where you've made a mistake.

Comment: @Arthur ok, I’ll add it

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702322/pkm-choose-pk-equiv-m-pmod-p?noredirect=1) for a general proof (Lucas' theorem). And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480059/a-problem-regarding-the-proof-of-pnk-choose-pn-equiv-k-mod-p-where-p-nmi?noredirect=1), why coprime is not needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A problem regarding the proof of ${p^nk\choose p^n}\equiv k\mod p$, where $p\nmid k$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480059/a-problem-regarding-the-proof-of-pnk-choose-pn-equiv-k-mod-p-where-p-nmi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true.  It follows from [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem)
$$ {a \choose b} \equiv \prod_k {a_k \choose b_k} \mod p $$
where $a = \sum_{k} a_k p^k$ and $ b = \sum_k b_k p^k$ are the base-$p$ representations of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Right, exactly the [above link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702322/pkm-choose-pk-equiv-m-pmod-p?noredirect=1).

Comment: Thanks. I didn’t know the Lucas theorem